# Regex - Transferring HTML to Markdown for ol tag

Tags: regex

I have been struggling with this regex for while.  I'm trying to transfer some HTML to mark down.

I have this code:

```
`"<ol>
   <li>This is a new list</li>
   <ol>
       <li>Embedded List</li>
       <li>Embedded List</li>
   </ol>
 </ol>"`
```

I need to add 4 space to all the `<li>` that are within **two** `<ol>`
So just the second to `<li>` elements need the 4 spaces.

The regex in pseudo code would be find all `<li>` preceded by  "`<ol>` any characters and `<ol>`.

This is what I tried so far `(?<=\"<ol>\r\n)(?<=[A-Za-z]<ol>\r\n)<li>` but no luck.  Is this even possible using regex?

Comment: Your html string is not valid. The first `li` is not closed. While it might be possible to use regex, a html parser will be more reliable.

Comment: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747)

Comment: So what you are telling me is not to use regex for this case.

Comment: Try [`(<li[^<]*>)([^>]*<\/li>)(?=(?![\s\S]*?<ol[^<]*>)[\s\S]*?<\/ol>)`](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4mM1/1).

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: If you think so, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(<li[^<]*>)([^>]*<\/li>)(?=(?![\s\S]*?<ol[^<]*>)[\s\S]*?<\/ol>)
```

Replace with `$1    $2`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4mM1/1)

The regex matches

- `(<li[^<]*>)` - matches and captures an opening `li` node
- `([^>]*<\/li>)` - matches and captures `li` node contents and closing `li` node
- `(?=(?![\s\S]*?<ol[^<]*>)[\s\S]*?<\/ol>)` - checks if there is any text and closing `ol` node, but no opening `ol` tag is before it.

**DISCLAIMER**: **Regex is not meant to parse HTML, use a proper parser instead. The current regex is just to show that it can process the sample input you provided.**